# Tablesorter Problem: Column Selector Widget demo problem

Tags: tablesorter

I tried to include the Column Selector Widget to a table and it didn't work. After a couple of hours i found out that in the demo file itself and the the given html template it differs. On the working demo the table begins with **two** header rows:

```html
<tr class="tablesorter-ignoreRow hasSpan" role="row">
  <th colspan="2" data-column="0" scope="col" role="columnheader" class="tablesorter01e6b87093a1e8columnselectorhasSpan" data-col-span="3">Student</th>
  <th colspan="3" data-column="3" scope="col" role="columnheader" class="tablesorter01e6b87093a1e8columnselectorhasSpan" data-col-span="4">Courses</th>
</tr>
<tr role="row" class="tablesorter-headerRow">
  <th data-priority="critical" data-column="0" class="tablesorter-header tablesorter-headerUnSorted" tabindex="0" scope="col" role="columnheader" aria-disabled="false" unselectable="on" style="user-select: none;" aria-sort="none" aria-label="Name: No sort applied, activate to apply an ascending sort"><div class="tablesorter-header-inner">Name</div></th>
...
</tr>
```

but in the HTML template it is instead only **one** header row

```html
<table class="tablesorter custom-popup">
  <thead>
<tr class="tablesorter-ignoreRow"> <!-- Ignore all cell content; disable sorting & form interaction  -->
  <th data-priority="critical">Name</th>
```

So if i get it right, the template cannot work at all, because the first (and here the only!) header row has a **"tablesorter-ignoreRow"-class** given.

When using the sourcecode of the page it now works for me mostly, but the colspan of the first row which includes "student" and "courses" is now confusing me. Is it right that i have to set the colspan and data-col-span-values to the highest possible number of columns in it?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that when loading bootstrap more than once the selector just doesn't work. Also when you mix bootsrap libs. So far I have not found the real problem. So I would search for the load order of the bootstrap libs